# Are there any knockoutjs page/routing frameworks?

Tags: knockout.js, javascript-framework

Coming from asp.net MVC 3.  In MVC4 they introduced WebAPI's.  It would be nice to be able to do all view/routes code in javascript and just rely on MVC for API.  Heck it's really cool that webapi's can be run independent of IIS!

That being said:

Are there any page frameworks that can leverage KnockoutJS which are similar to my mock-up below:

```
Framework.RegisterRoutes(..,mainViewModel);//sets the CurrentViewModel?
```

Each route being a separate file of a viewModel, and a view to be injected into the master view

```
var mainviewModel= function(){
   var self = this;
   self.CurrentViewModel = ko.observable();
   ...
   return self;
}

<div id="mainPageContent" data-bind:'html:CurrentViewModel.Render'>
</div>
```

I know that a lot of this can be achieved by self, but not sure how to achieve the register routes/ loading separate files

I feel like knockoutjs's main strengths is the ability to not intrude into the way you code js (ie build an object/framework how you want so long as the interacting objects are observable)

Comment: you should check [sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Pager.js](http://pagerjs.com/) is a URL routing framework built specifically for use with Knockout.js.   Make sure you go through the entire [Demo](http://pagerjs.com/demo/) to see its full power and flexibility.  IMHO, it far exceeds PathJS and Sammy.

Comment: Can I just ask why none of these available routing frameworks make use of the HTML5 History functionality? Everything is using a hashbang #! when HistoryJS only falls back to that for Google SEO purposes... am I missing something here? - https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: As far as I understood from the docs, html5 history is supported using historyJS. It even has a code example showing how to enable it. html5 history means that the google web crawler can navigate your site, but it isn't limited to just crawler traffic.

Comment: I was really impressed when looking at pager. Sammy always seems to be the framework of choice but I really like how pager fits into the knockout way of doing things. Nice one!

Comment: I am using this successfully in several projects that are enterprise scale

Comment: The history API IS SUPPORTED in Pager.js! go have a look at the docs

Comment: I've looked at Pager.JS and honestly, it looks a bit overwhelming. I still haven't grokked how would I trigger a function via a navigation event instead of handling the 'click' manually.

Answer (score 21):

[Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) is an excellent lightweight routing JavaScript library. You can do things like this to route when used in pair with Knockout (from the tutorials web site or KnockoutJS):

```
$.sammy(function() {
    this.get('#:folder', function() {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenMailData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { folder: this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
    });

    this.get('#:folder/:mailId', function() {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenFolderData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { mailId: this.params.mailId }, self.chosenMailData);
    });

    this.get('', function() {
        this.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox');
    });
}).run();
```

Another option is to use SproutCore, but its so much more than nav, so I dont recommend that route unless you want all of SproutCore. There are plenty of other libraries, but I like Sammy.js so far due to how lightweight it is.

Comment: Interesting. Would you say that Sammy.js is limited by itself, and that one should should use KnockoutJS library in addition? (I'm not sure which parts of the code you showed are knockout related).

Comment: the code i showed above is all Sammy.js related. Knockout handles data binding for you. Sammy can be use with it to do the routing. I like it because its simple, stable and powerful.

Comment: The biggest problem I see here is for every view you need to have a new call in every route to 'self.correspondingObservable(null'

Comment: @pnewhook - Yes, I agree. That's where DRY comes in. Most of this code is repeated for each "get", so I create a function that encapsulates the routing setup logic. Then I pass in an array of object literals that contain information for each route. Makes the code very tight and completely reusable across projects.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to throw my hat in the running to future Googlers/SOers with [ko-component-router](http://github.com/profiscience/ko-component-router).

IMO the API is much more succinct than Pager.js, and having been designed explicitly for KO it has built in goodies like observable route & querystring parameters.

Best of all, it's actively maintained and will remain so for the forseeable future.

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm the developer of this package.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [PathJs](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs) with some success, there is also [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/) which is more of a framework. Neither of these are KO specific.

A more heavyweight but KO optimized solution would be [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: pathjs works great, i just cannot get my loaded html to data-bind to the parent pageviewmodel.currentviewmodel

Comment: @maxfridbe - that sounds like a separate issue. Can you post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Knockback page has no documentation on it. How does one even start with it?

Comment: @drozzy - There are some docs on the github page https://github.com/kmalakoff/knockback

Answer (score 2):

Older question, but for reference Durandal is an excellent SPA framework for Knockout:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Introduction/

Comment: Something to be aware of it appears Durandal is being merged with angular.js sadly. http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/angular-and-durandal-converge/

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm in a "wait-and-see" mode as the current Angular 2.0 stuff looks as weird/complex as Angular 1.0.   Durandal 2.x does everything I need at this point

Comment: Durandal is now moving to Aurelia, "The Next Generation of Durandal" http://aurelia.io/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I just open-sourced the mini SPA framework I put together with Knockout being the major component.

**knockout-spa**
A mini (but full-fledged) SPA framework built on top of Knockout, Require, Director, Sugar.
https://github.com/onlyurei/knockout-spa

**Live Demo:**
http://knockout-spa.mybluemix.net

#### Features

- Routing (based on Flatiron's Director): HTML5 history (pushState) or hash.
- Highly composable and reusable: pick modules/components for a page in the page-specific JS and they will be auto-wired for the page's HTML template
- SEO ready (prerender.io)
- Fast and lightweight (85 KB of JS minified and gizpped)
- Two-tier bundle build for JS for production: common module that will be used by most pages, and page-specific modules that will be lazy-loaded
- Organized folder structure to help you stay sane for organizing and reusing JS, CSS, HTML
- Using Knockout 3.3.0+ so ready for Knockout's flavor of web component and custom tags (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html)
- All documentation are in the major dependencies' own homepages, so that you don't need to completely learn a new framework

  - Knockout http://knockoutjs.com
  - Require http://requirejs.org
  - Director https://github.com/flatiron/director
  - jQuery http://jquery.com
  - Sugar http://sugarjs.com

Comment: hey, I am also in the process to add prerender.io to a KO based SPA. How did you make prerender.io integration work? I've only seen solution for middleware or apache/nginx. In your knockout-spa code there's only one line in the whole codebase that seem to be related to prerender, and it's in index.html but does not tell me a lot.. is that enough?

Comment: Hi there I use https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node middleware for the Node backend (Sails which is based on Express).

Comment: Oh, ok, won't work for me, I am using a baas so I can't use any middleware