# Knockout.js data bind for finding partial strings in urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need a data bind using Knockout.js to find if a url returned by a function contains a partial string in the url.

This is the JavaScript equivalent but how does this translate into a data bind using knockout.js?

```
var url = myURL();
var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

if (lastPart === "#tab") {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You can do this with either a computed value or a custom binding, but you havent provided enough information to give you an answer. Update your question with a jsfiddle showing the problem and I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about routing or page using knockout, [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705078/are-there-any-knockoutjs-page-routing-frameworks)
. [Pager](http://pagerjs.com/) may be the one you are looking for. Pager JS is url routing framework based on `Knockout & Jquery`for single page application.
Here is the [sample using Sammy JS](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.sg/2012/10/a-single-page-app-with-knockoutjs.html) with knockout.