# .NET webapp using knockout + webApi: should I also leave Razor syntax or use only html files?

Tags: .net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2

I am going to create a web application using .NET. 
I have choosen to use `Knockout` for front end and for service I will use `WebApi`.

I have seen two approaches:

1) using only `html` files; in this case no Razor syntax is ever used

vs

2) using 'cshtml' files; in this case Knockout html markup will be used in most cases, but sometimes some Razor things are also possible. I am not sure if this is useful, but I imagine that sometimes could be.

In this case first call would be through MVC controller, that will load cshtml file and appropriate Knockout model (that will consume webapi services). Am I right?

Which approach would be better?

P.S. From Knockout perspective I would like to use it as described in this example: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html#Spam/52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I feel you should have `.cshtml` as shell/container only, all the views should be in `HTML`, this will be better in terms of performance as the `HTML` gets cached in clients browser.

When you have `.cshtml` as a shell, you will have more control over the application and it will be easy for you to implement bundling, minification, security, logging etc at server side.

This approach really works well if you have a single page application (`SPA`), where you are using any routing engine to load your views/partials (html).

Comment: I am no sure I understand the right meaning by "shell". It is something like first page (wrapper, container) ? And how you include other html files into this shell?

Comment: I can give example of angularjs where your chtml will just hold bundles and a tag for view, where the html will be loaded as partials by the routing engine

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705078/are-there-any-knockoutjs-page-routing-frameworks

Comment: Thank you. Basically this means I have to use some client side routing library?

Comment: It will be good, it will make your application modular and easy to maintain